# How to generate a multi-dimensional array from a PDO resultset?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo, resultset

I am trying to make an array using the resultset from a PDO query.

I am not sure how to generete my desired array structure.

```
require_once("../resource/Database.php");

$query ="SELECT username FROM users";
$select = $db->prepare($query);
$select->execute(array());  
foreach($select as $rs) :          
    $testing = "array('city'=>".$rs['citynames']"),"

$cities = array(
    echo $testing;
);
```

I would like this result:

```
$names= array(
    array('name'=>'Los Angeles'),
    array('name'=>'Chicago'),
    array('name'=>'Houston'),
    array('name'=>'Phoenix'),
    array('name'=>'Philadelphia'),
    array('name'=>'San Antonio'),
    array('name'=>'Dallas',),
    array('name'=>'San Diego',),
    array('name'=>'San Jose', ),
    array('name'=>'Detroit', ),
    array('name'=>'San Francisco',),
    array('name'=>'Jacksonville', ),
    array('name'=>'Indianapolis', ),
    array('name'=>'Austin', ),
    array('name'=>'Columbus', ),
    array('name'=>'Fort Worth',),
    array('name'=>'Charlotte', ),
    array('name'=>'Memphis', ),
    array('name'=>'Baltimore', ),
);
```

Comment: This feels like extra handling.  You could just use an alias of `name` on the `username` column in your query.  What is the next step?  Why are you preparing your resultset data this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are trying to do this?

```
require_once("../resource/Database.php");
$query ="SELECT username FROM users";
$select = $db->prepare($query);
$select->execute(array());
# You may have a snippet of code that you are missing, but incase not,
# you have to fetch the results while() to iterate or your results. I just
# copied your code and focused on the push, not the fact you didn't fetch
while($rs = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $names[] = array('name'=>$rs['citynames']);
}
```

This is an array push found here [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). If this is not what you mean, you will have to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the sql query output format :

```
$query ="SELECT username FROM users";
$select = $db->prepare($query);
$select->execute(array());  
foreach($select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $rs) {
   $testing[] = array('city' => $rs['citynames']);
}

var_dump($testing);
```